# Can I make my Nikon DSLR put photos in separate folders per day?

Tags: nikon, sdcard, filenames, date

When I take photos, I want my camera to create a folder for that specific date, and when I take photos on another day, it'll have a folder for *that* specific day, and so on. During thtransfer of my photos from SD card to computer, it would be easier to see the dates on which I took the photos. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to assign a date-based filename on-camera. However, there are quite a few pieces of software that will help do just this when ingesting photos from the memory card to your computer, giving you the ability to define your preferred file name, folder structure, and assorted metadata, too, such as [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom.html) and [Camera Bits Photo Mechanic](http://www.camerabits.com/).

Comment: For what it's worth (not much, I suppose, but in case this is a _really_ important feature to someone and they can't live with your suggestion for doing it on "ingestion", there's no way on this Nikon model, but it _is_ possible on some other brands of DSLR.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with Dropbox, Using the automatic import function will rename all of your files to the datetime taken. My process is:

1) Plug SD card into computer (in my case it's an iMac)
2) Let dropbox do the automatic import
3) Have hazel automatically file into my Pictures folder with the structure Year/Month/Day Taken 
4) In Lightroom, I use the synchronize folder function to import any recently added photos

I have a separate hazel rule that deletes files from the dropbox camera uploads folder a 1 week after they were taken. So really, dropbox is just a temporary holding place for my files.

Answer (score 0):

Nikon assigns sequential filenames to the pictures, but it does record the date, which will show up in the date column on your PC.  I usually have a separate folder on the PC for each day I shoot.

So, as long as you have correctly set the date and time on your camera, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load your photos (which I do daily) onto your computer and when you "select all" you can rename your photos in a zip.  It doesn't take but a few tries to get that right. If you see a set of photos you want to put in its own group for a certain day, then "highlite" just those photos by pressing control then enter then rename to your discretion (by date or occasion) This make it alot easier than trying to put all this to a camera (which some cameras will put a date on each photo). Hope this helps.